# Check variable of modules in package

Tags: python, python-module

My python project has the following file structure:

```
/main.py
/functions
/functions/func1.py
/functions/func2.py
/functions/func3.py
/funcitons/__init__.py
```

Every func.py file has a variable 'CAN_USE'. In some files it's true in other false.
How can I check inside of my main.py which func.py files has 'CAN_USE' variable equals true?

Comment: What determines the value of this `CAN_USE`? You might want to use `__all__` instead.

Comment: Now CAN_USE is determined by developer of func.py. If false then client who uses the function won't see this func.py. And about \_\_all\_\_ - I guess it works only when I know names of functions? I want it more dynamically, at least in the client modules - like main.py in my example. So no func.py names in main.py just package name 'functions'. From my point of view it is better practice. Correct me if I wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pkgutil` you can find all modules in a package:

```
import pkgutil

def usable_modules(package_name):
    modules = pkgutil.iter_modules([package_name])
    usable = []
    for importer, name, ispkg in modules:
        module = pkgutil.find_loader('{0}.{1}'.format(package_name, name)).\
                                                             load_module(name)
        if hasattr(module, 'CAN_USE') and module.CAN_USE:
            usable.append(module)
    return usable

print(usable_modules('functions'))
```

Note that this also checks other modules in your package (e.g. `__init__.py`). You can filter them out in your loop if you want to (e.g. `if not name.startswith('func'): continue`).

Comment: It looks like the best solution that I have saw in all world wide web. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in main.py

```
from functions import func1, func2, func3
print func1.CAN_USE
print func2.CAN_USE
print func3.CAN_USE
```

Comment: Is there any solution without explicitly naming func.py files? For example, if I add 20 functions in functions package it wouldn't look like good solution. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct, this is just a quick and easy way to do it. For a dynamic approach you want to take a look at @Rob Wouters answer =)